# Is it possible to obtain a reference of containing class (CDI)?

Tags: java, cdi, weld, jboss-weld, weld2

My setup is as below -

```
public class ParentModel {
    private StatusModel sm;
}
```

`StatusModel` class is as below -

```
public class StatusModel {
    private ParentModel pm;

    public void setParentModel(ParentModel pm) {
        this.pm = pm;
    }
}
```

`pm` inside `StatusModel` is the reference of `ParentModel` instance upon which the `StatusModel` depends.

Inside `dao` - I'm injecting `ParentModel` as below

```
@Inject
private Instance<ParentModel> factory;
```

but, setting `ParentModel` reference to `StatusModel` using a separate method call as below -

```
pm = factory.get();
pm.setters...
pm.getSm().setParentModel(pm);//<----- is it possible to avoid this?
```

Can we obtain the `pm` reference inside `sm` without a method call?

Comment: It’s a cyclic dependency, there’s no unambiguous way for a DI container to correctly determine the order in which to create the objects. Lateral suggestion: don’t; instead, extract the functionality that `StatusModel` needs into a new class you can inject into both it and `ParentModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which object may be, however briefly, in an incompletely initialized state, inject that object into the other one as a constructor parameter, and call the setter there. The whole object hierarchy will then be consistent when you resolve the latter object:

```
class ParentModel {
    StatusModel _status;
    ParentModel(@Inject StatusModel status) {
        _status = status;
        _status.setParent(this);
    }
}

class StatusModel {
    ParentModel _parent;
    void setParent(ParentModel parent) { _parent = parent);
}
```

---

That said, I would suggest breaking this cyclic dependency up, because then you can restore a nice-to-have property of the design where it’s impossible to construct invalid objects.